# Portfolio not loading properly in mobile view

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I made this portfolio and it worked for desktop view but in mobile view it's not working and breaking down
https://ruizxzx.github.io/Portfolio/

can anyone please tell what to do?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

If u need HTML code then comment it i will provide u with it

THANKYOU!!

CSS:

```
body {
    color: #40514E;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;


}

h1 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-family: 'Sacramento', serif;
    color: #66BFBF;
    font-size: 560%;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}



h3 {
    font-family: "adobe-garamond-pro", serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;
    color: #11999E;
}
h2 {
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    font-variation-settings: 'wght' 100;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #66BFBF;
    
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.pro {
    color: rgb(111, 91, 91);
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight:bold;

}
.top-container {
    background-color: #476b7827;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}




.top-cloud {
    position: relative;
    right: 450px;
    top: 100px;

}

.bottom-cloud {
    position: relative;
    left: 450px;
    bottom: 300px;
}

.mountain {
    position: relative;

}
.dp {
    width: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;

}
.coder-img {
    height: 300px;
}

.photographer-img {
    height: 300px;
}
.skill-row {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 2;
}
p {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 2;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.skill-heading {
    color: #01777b;
    font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.coder-img {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.soundify-img {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.photographer-img {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px 15px 10px 0px;
    padding: 20px;
 
}



.top-hr {
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}



hr {
    border-style: none;
    border-top-style: dotted;
    border-color: rgb(70, 142, 183);
    border-width: 10px;
    width: 5%;
    margin: 100px auto;
    
    }
.bio {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    width: 30%;
    margin: auto;
}

.pic {
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.contact-me {
    margin: 1px auto 60px; 
    width: 40%;

}
.dev {
    width: 100%;
}
.soundify-bio {
    margin: auto;
}
.btn {
    background: #67C0C0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #67C0C0, #3c5959);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #67C0C0, #3c5959);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #67C0C0, #3c5959);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #67C0C0, #3c5959);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #67C0C0, #3c5959);
    -webkit-border-radius: 10;
    -moz-border-radius: 10;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .btn:hover {
    background: #1fc2bf;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1fc2bf, #39bf80);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1fc2bf, #39bf80);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1fc2bf, #39bf80);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1fc2bf, #39bf80);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1fc2bf, #39bf80);
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .bottom-container {
    background-color: #93cdcc;
    padding: 50px 0px 3px;
  }

  a {
    color: #58a4a7;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    font-size: normal;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    margin: 10px 20px;

  }
  a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .copyright {
    color: #f6f6f6;
    font-size: 75%;
  }
```

It's working fine in desktop browsers but i was it to be work in mobile view as well.
IM NEW BTW!

Comment: Looks like your header background image is spilling out of its container, triggering a horizontal scroll bar. To avoid mobile style issues, it’s best practice to build mobile-first I.e. style for a small display and use media queries to adjust elements as more space becomes available on bigger screens

Answer (score 0):

When you are designing HTML/CSS for multiple platforms, you need to be aware that different resolutions will behave differently. So, I would advise you to use breakpoints using [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_media_query_breakpoints.asp), so you can have different parameters for special resolutions.

In the majority of the styles you showed you are using px as unity, so it will try to make it's size fixed to the pixels you defined, but different resolutions and different pixel density screens will behave not the same, so would be better to use vh (viewheight), vw (viewwidth) and % as it will have a more previsible behaviour, see more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.php).

Answer (score 0):

This project is from Angela Yu's web development course. She will teach responsive design in the upcoming lessons. This design is not responsive. Absolute units ( px , in , mm , cm , pt , and pc ) are as bad for accessibility and responsive design . Try using viewport relative or font relative units.